# Exception while recursively deleting files and folders in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, recursion, isolatedstorage

I am trying to delete a folder from Isolated Storage which has files and folders inside recursively. I am using a piece of code suggested by others on Stackoverflow and other blogs. The code is as follows:

```
private void deleteSubApp(string pappname)
  {
      try
      {
          string directory = "apps/" + pappname;
          IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
          if (iso.DirectoryExists(directory))
          {
              string[] files = iso.GetFileNames(directory + @"/*");
              foreach (string file in files)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      iso.DeleteFile(directory + @"/" + file);
                  }

              }

              string[] subDirectories = iso.GetDirectoryNames(directory + @"/*");
              foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      deleteSubApp(directory + @"/" + subDirectory);
                  }

              }

              iso.DeleteDirectory(directory);

          }
      }
  }
```

Since Windows Phone 8 does not allow a built in function to delete a folder unless its empty, deleting it recursively as the above code remains the only option. But when i run the code, i get an exception which is:

> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to delete,
>   directory not empty or does not exist.

Please help to find any errors in the code, due to which it is failing? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't the recursive call be `deleteSubApp(pappname + @"/" + subDirectory);` to avoid having something like "apps/apps/..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
deleteSubApp(directory + @"/" + subDirectory);
```

To

```
deleteSubApp(pappname + @"/" + subDirectory);
```

Otherwise you pass in something like "apps/pappname/subdirectory" on the recursive call and it will set `directory` to "apps/apps/pappname/subdirectory" which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you... I actually figured out the mistake the same day itself. Its the same as you have pointed out.